# How to change model data of a view from another view?

Tags: sapui5

**viewtest** is bound to a JSONModel. **View2** is bound to the same JSONModel by creating a reference to **viewtest** and setting the model to viewtest.getModel().

What I'm trying to do is modify the shared model data in **View3** by clicking a button so that the texts in textfield and textview will change automatically. However, the texts in textfield and textview remain "This is a text". What's the problem?

The index.html file:
[image]

and the viewtest.view.js file:

```js
sap.ui.jsview("viewtest.viewtest", {
 getControllerName : function() {
  return "viewtest.viewtest";
 },
 createContent : function(oController) {
    this.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel());
  var oData = {
    text: "this is a text"
  };
  this.getModel().setData(oData);
  var oTextField = new sap.ui.commons.TextField({value: "{/text}"});
  return [oTextField];
 }
});
```

View2.view.js file:

```js
sap.ui.jsview("viewtest.View2", {
 getControllerName : function() {
  return "viewtest.View2";
 },
 createContent : function(oController) {
  var viewtest = sap.ui.view({viewName: "viewtest.viewtest", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
  this.setModel(viewtest.getModel());
  this.getModel().setData(viewtest.getModel().getData());
  var oTextView = new sap.ui.commons.TextView({text: "{/text}"});
  return [oTextView];
 }
});
```

View3.view.js file:

```js
sap.ui.jsview("viewtest.View3", {
 getControllerName : function() {
  return "viewtest.View3";
 },
 createContent : function(oController) {
  var oButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button({text:"click", press: func});
  function func() {
   var oView = new sap.ui.view({viewName:"viewtest.viewtest", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
   oView.getModel().setData({text:"hello world"}, true);
  }
  return [oButton];
 }
});
```

Comment: view2 and view3 are getting new instances of viewtest. They all need to share the same instance of viewtest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion. Maybe it is worth to give in your .html file id to every view, and then in view3 update and set model to each one of the views by calling them by id?
Like,
in index.html:

```
var view1 = new sap.ui.view({id:"view1", viewName:"viewtest.View1", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
```

and then in view3:

```
function func() {
    var oView = sap.ui.getCore().byId("view1");
    oView.getModel().setData({text:"hello world"}, true);
    oView.getModel().refresh(); //if setting new model won't update the views
}
```

Or, if you use the same model in all your views, set model not to each view separately, but to the core:

viewtest.view.js file:

```
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel());
```

thus, you don't need to set model in view2.